# Filters alternatives for Quarkus

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-rest-client

I'm currently working on a tech migration for a big client's service and I'm having trouble finding a package other than javax.ws.rs.client for applying filters to my Quarkus service. Is there another library or package for filter creation and management in Quarkus? Thank you. Regards.

Comment: Which extensions do you plan to use?

Comment: for the moment the most documented and implemented is the one that JAX- RS offers

Comment: why not use `ContainerRequestFilter` ?

Answer (score 1):

I am using quarkus-undertow which comes with java servlet-api.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-undertow</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

All you need now is a class e.g. `CustomWebFilter.java`:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpFilter;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebFilter(urlPatterns = "/*")
public class CustomWebFilter extends HttpFilter {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

        // your filter handling
        
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

}
```